# ASP.NET WebForms Domain Routing

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes, webforms

I have seen a cool implementation of ASP.NET MVC Domain Routing.
Source: http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2009/05/20/ASPNET-MVC-Domain-Routing.aspx

Could this be done on ASP.NET WebForms 4.0?

Comment: -1 for what? would the down-voter care to elaborate? i guess not :)

Comment: Sorry for being off topic but except the fact this is a cool trick with domain routing, what use it have? I mean what difference it makes to have www.website.com/en or www.en.website.com. I think for end users it will be much more clear to have default ROUTES aka domain name . domain name type / controllers ...

Comment: @eugeneK: work with a multi tenant multi lingual website and you would know. i am sorry that you had not :)

Comment: I did and actually current project of mine is. I still see no point in using www.en.website.com instead of www.website.com/en which is far more readable and doesn't require to trick Routing mechanism ( which probably causes more CPU/Memory usage )...

Answer (score 1):

Considering the fact that the Route class is not specific to MVC apps and can be easily used within the context of a plain ASP .NET WebForms project the DomainRoute class you linked to should work just fine in that context as well.

Should be an easy enough venture to prove out.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is yes. It's actually pretty simple. You could try the DomainRoute class or just write your own url rewriting module and be good to go. But basically you would use something like this:

http://www.gutgames.com/post/Url-Rewriting-in-ASPNet.aspx

And instead of the Path, you'd use the Url property and parse it however you want. Or you could just use an open source project like this:

http://sharedhostingsplittr.codeplex.com/

And modify it slightly if need be.

Comment: thanks, but instead of url rewriting, i would like to extend url routing itself

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that yes, you can use routing in WebForms.  Look into the `System.Web.Routing` namespace.

In your `Application_Start` in your Global.asax you can set up routes based on text or regular expressions.

Comment: @skaz: Please give me one reason on why shouldn't I down vote this!

Comment: @yetanothercoder - Not sure what you want.  You asked "could this be done."  Yes, it can be done.  And I gave you homework to look into.  I don't know what response you wanted...

Comment: @skaz: we are talking about domain routing here. I do know about System.Web.Routing. Did you read the blog post?

Comment: I would think a down vote would be a bit harsh. your original post didn't mention that you knew anything about routing. @skaz answered your question, although a bit more detail would have avoid these comments.

Comment: @Simon Halsey: if you have read the question and gone through the blog post you would have understood. plus i did not down vote skaz.

Comment: @naveen, with all due respect if you could be more specific what are you trying to do in your question, others wouldn't probably answer. I did visit your link and read what this for BUT IT IS UP TO YOU TO BE CLEAR IN YOUR QUESTION. NOONE WORKS FOR YOU HERE

Comment: @eugeneK: i don't mind :) to me, my question is complete. thats just me.

Comment: What suggested to you that hadn't read the question and the blog? As @eugeneK said, I don't work here & don't like people being rude to me. You'll also note the use of "would be" instead of "is", hence if you were, in the future, ie you haven't already, voted down then and only then would it be harsh.

Answer (score 0):

Yes add Global.ascx file in your project and add a function in it written by me

```
   public static void UrlRouting(RouteCollection RC, string RoutName, string routeUrl, string Page)
    {
        RC.MapPageRoute(RoutName, routeUrl, Page);
    }
after this inside Application_Start event on global.ascx file 
call that function like 
UrlRouting(RouteTable.Routes, "index", "Home", "~/index.aspx");
```

and then call it with route URL which is ~/Home 
'>Home
Note: Don't forget to call ResolveUrl with your URL otherwise it cannot be called 
and your images and jquery,js paths should also have ResolveUrl 
like 
'/>
otherwise this jquery will not work and images will not be displayed 
Hope this will help